# elastic exporter - connection refused

Tags: elasticsearch, prometheus

trying to set up elastic exporter for a local stack :
https://github.com/prometheus-community/elasticsearch_exporter

I get a **connection refused** when running with a docker even when xpack security is disabled.

```
xpack.license.self_generated.type: basic
xpack.security.enabled: false
xpack.monitoring.collection.enabled: true
xpack.monitoring.exporters.my_local_exporter:
  type: local

bootstrap.memory_lock: true
search.allow_expensive_queries: true
indices.memory.index_buffer_size: 30%
```

I use elastic 8.1.2 :

```
{
  "name" : "0a166124ca20",
  "cluster_name" : "docker-cluster",
  "cluster_uuid" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "8.1.2",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "docker",
    "build_hash" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "build_date" : "2022-03-29T21:18:59.991429448Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "9.0.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "7.17.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "7.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

I get limited amount of metrics but missing the majoriy
for example --> elasticsearch_node_stats_up 0

here is my docker-compose:

```
elasticsearch_exporter:
    image: quay.io/prometheuscommunity/elasticsearch-exporter:latest
    command:
    - '--es.uri=http://localhost:9200'
    - '--es.ssl-skip-verify'
    - '--es.all'
    restart: always
    environment:
    - 'ES_API_KEY=Apikey xxxxxxxxxx'
    ports:
    - "9114:9114"
```

Comment: drive-by comment as I'm unfamiliar with Elastic. It appears you're running `elasticsearch_exporter` using Docker Compose. The service references (I assume the Elasticsearch server) as `http://localhost:9200`. `localhost` refers to the service when using Docker Compose i.e. `elasticsearch_exporter`. If you're running Elastic as another Docker Compose service (let's say it's called 'elastic`, then you should reference it from the `elasticsearch_exporter` service as `http://elastic:9200`

Comment: If you're running Elasticsearch on the host machine and the port `9200` refers to the host (on which you're running Docker Compose), then you will need to bind the Docker Compose services to the host's network in order to access the host's port from the service. To do this you want to use `network_mode: "host"`. See [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#network_mode)

Comment: thanks, I started it on another server so I won't have to point it to localhost and you are toatally right, i have to point to the http://<service>:9200 as you mentioed...Thanks so much